# Как организовать структуру мультиязычного сайта?

Tags: php, смена-языка

Есть онлайн игра, реализованная на веб-сайте. Есть несколько сопровождающих игрока подсказок, описаний, подписей и т.п. Как правильно организовать мультиязычность на сайте? Как это делают в большинстве случаев?

Answer (score 1):

Вы не уточнили фреймворк и/или используемые библиотеки, поэтому рассмотрим общий случай.

Локализация — это, конечно, больше, чем просто перевод текстов (это и даты, и — иногда — размещение элементов, и даже адаптация содержимого под определённую культуру). Однако пойдём от простого.
Я бы советовал применять [GNU GetText](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext).

Плюсы:

- Простота добавления и обновления переводов (.PO-файлы для переводчика, .MO-файлы для машинной обработки — первые легко держать в системе контроля версий, вторые генерируются одной простой командой);
- Значительно более читаемый и легко поддерживаемый код (это спорно, но за 10 лет работы в локализации я ничего удобнее не видел): `_('Please input your name:')` вместо какого-нибудь `$messages['pleaseInputName']` или чего-то похожего. Поменялось сообщение — меняем английский оригинал, регенерируем POT-каталог, обновляем переводы (или сразу отдаём каталог переводчикам, в зависимости от их квалификации) — и всё, никакой головной боли;
- При небольшой донастройке правильная плюрализация, то есть употребление форм множественного числа («1 книга, 2 книги, 5 книг» для русского языка, «1 book, 2 books, 5 books» для английского, а в арабском этих форм не то пять, не то шесть для разного количества объектов);
- Чёткая структура папок с локализованными файлами, никакого зоопарка местоположений и форматов.

Поддержка в PHP осуществляется с помощью [расширения GetText](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php). Оно вроде как опционально, но я, честно говоря, уже давно почти нигде не видел сборок без него.

Comment: Хорошее решение, а как лучше поступить с сообщениями сгенерированными JS скриптами?

Comment: Я не большой спец в JS, но после гугления понял, что всё вроде как достаточно печально: в основном люди используют некий PO2JSON-конвертер, а потом библиотеки работают уже с JSON-файлами (посмотрите, например, Jet или GetText.js).